# Does Find Rare Items actually work?

Tags: borderlands

In Borderlands, some COMs like Scavenger and Catalyst can come with a bottom line bonus which is either +1 or +2 Find Rare Items. What's this do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some wonderfully scientific [work](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/usernote.php?do=viewuser&u=47703) [404] done by [Scottes](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/member.php?u=47703) [404] over on the Gearbox Software Forums. He summarizes, "I can't tell the difference between FRI and non-FRI runs."  In other words, Find Rare Items does nothing.

Here are his two posts on the topic: [1](https://web.archive.org/web/20110815134817/http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=103825) and [[404]](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?p=2121062&postcount=171).

Comment: Links are no longer valid.  Bummer.  For what it’s worth, I *am* observing a difference, but only in the items dropped by enemies and found in skag piles.  Chests and vendors seem unaffected.  I’m still not sure about lockers.  Someday I shall do a proper statistical analysis…

Comment: @VGR: yeah, I'd be curious to know if this was fixed with GOTY, GOTY Enhanced etc. Those threads are from ~2010 or so, when a lot more stuff was broken in this game.